# Accessing headers set in express.js in the front end code

Tags: javascript, http, express, axios

Is there a way I can set my headers in express.js to be accessible in my front end javascript code. I use axios for my http calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the header respanse as below

```
res.set({
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  'Content-Length': '5656565'
})
```

or

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

you can also let cors handle it for you

```
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors());
```

and on your frontend you can read the respanse header , using axios

```
axios.head("/", { params: {"foo": "bar"}})
     .then(response => console.info("headers:", response.headers)
```